# What is the best practice for signing a message with Gnosis?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, gnosis-safe

I’m a little confused about signing a message with Gnosis
We have a semi decentralized app
And we want the Gnosis user to sign a message off chain and then we verify it on chain,
For signing the message should I use “signMessageLib” or “approveHash”!!?
And for the verification should I use the fallbackhandler “isValidSignature” or the safe “checkSignature” functions!?